# Excute for loop in subfolder

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have this command :

```
for i in $(svn st | grep \! | awk '{print $2}'); do svn delete $i; done
```

I would like to execute it to a subfolder without making a cd command.
Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this counts.  If the problem is just that you don't want to use a `cd` because you don't want to have `cd` back, you can use a subshell using the `( ... )` notation.  You can change directory inside the parens but it's discarded when you exit.  Try this and you'll see instantly what it does:

```
( cd ..; pwd); pwd
```

If you're really insistent you don't want to see the `cd` command anywhere in the loop, you could use a procedure as a wrapper to hide it.